# Change format date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects, dom-events

I want to change the format in JavaScript, to be Year-month-day
I used this code to get 3 months before, but the format that was generated became like this 9/19/2019.
This my code:

```
var d = new Date();
    d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
    var x = d.toLocaleDateString();
    console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get Year, Month and Date and use string interpolation like below

```js
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 3);
    
var formattedDate = `${d.getFullYear()}-${(d.getMonth() + 1)}-${d.getDate()}`;
  console.log(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the toLocaleDateString() which will format to the result you received which is expected.

Reference Mozilla's Docs on [Date()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to get the right function for you there :)

Most instances you are able to just piece it together yourself similar to:

```
const date = `${date.getYear()}/${date.getMonth()}/${date.getDay()}`;
```

It's not a nice solution but there are a lot of restrictions with OOTB `Date()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/), a lightweight and handy library for this purpose:

```
var d = moment(new Date()).subtract(3, 'months').format('dd-MMM-yyyy);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = d.toISOString().substring(0,10);
console.log(x);

//it will give you the format of y-m-d
```